# Change touch keyboard layout from within Blazor app?

Tags: blazor

I'm writing a simple Blazor app to be run on Windows 10. Target framework is .Net 5.0. I want to change the touch screen keyboard's layout by just clicking a button, but is it possible?

I managed to change the layout by executing a powerscript manually (involving Set-WinUserLanguageList and Set-WinDefaultInputMethodOverride), but when I try to execute it from the app it has no effect.

Why?

Is there another way? Is there any way at all?

Comment: If a web application executing code to make system changes sounds like a terrible and dangerous idea, it's because it is and it's also why it's not a thing.

Comment: Why?  Such functionality would blow a nuclear hole through device security.  Is there another way?  Based on the previous statement, draw your own conclusion.

Comment: It's a site to be run on a touch-screen (kiosk mode), and I want to present the touch keyboard in different languages depending on who logs in to the site. How would you go about to do this?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Comment: I read somewhere that it is possible by using Winforms, but I haven't tried it out yet. I solved it by using a 3rd party Javascript keyboard instead.